# Riddle Riddle in numbers!

Tags: riddle

Here is a simple riddle about numbers.

> How would you insert 4 inside 5?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> FIVE

Which is

> F(IV)E

Where

> IV = 4

So we acheieved

> 4(IV) inside 5 (FIVE)

Comment: Quickly done! I think it should be "achieved" tho ;)

Answer (score 12):

[image: I may not be taking this seriously enough...]

I might not be taking this question seriously enough...

Comment: Lois: Peter, this is for the win, say the word "what".
Peter: Wow. Okay. This really separates the men from the boys.

Lois: Peter, just say "What"!!

Peter: Yeah, yeah. Yeah, now, Lois. This is not a race. Okay, I wanna say "who." Oh, boy. Fantastic Four. Fantastic Four, steak, steak, steak, steak, a small amount of peas. Is it "what?"

Lois: That's right. You win, Peter. You did it.

Answer (score 5):

As an apology for my previous answer, I'd like to offer the following:

> Five fenceposts can have four panels of fencing placed between them.

And,

> A '5' lit up on a 7-segment display will have four interior right angles. (By coincidence of it being made of also 5 distinct segments.)

And stretching it,

> according to Wikipedia's page of [List of numbers in various languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numbers_in_various_languages), there are no languages where the common word for 'four' is a subset or anagram subset of the word for 'five', at least as far as I could tell with my layman's eye, which was a bit of a disappointment. But graphically speaking, in the Tai-Kadai language Lao, 4 could fit into 5 quite neatly. [image: Tai-Kadai language].

Comment: I like that numbering system. "Okay, we have two loops and some curves. What should we do for the next number?" "I think another loop would be appropriate."